# How to change name referenced in a for loop -- R

Tags: r, for-loop, linear-programming

I have a linear program in my R code. I am passing data frames through it that have similar names "FP_2013_01", "FP_2013_02",  "FP_2014_01", etc. I would like the for loop to adjust the "2013" and "01" values dynamically, so I don't have to repeat the process over and over again. Here is the linear program:

```
num_constraints <- 5
dec_var <-length(FP_2013_01$PLAYER)
test <- make.lp(num_constraints,dec_var)
set.type(test,{1:dec_var},"binary")
set.objfn(test,c(FP_2013_01$avg_FD_PTS))
set.row(test,1,c(FP_2013_01$Wk1))
set.row(test,2,c(POS_FP_2013_01$QB))
set.constr.type(test,c(3,3,3,3),{2:5})
set.row(test,3,c(POS_FP_2013_01$RB))
set.row(test,4,c(POS_FP_2013_01$WR))
set.row(test,5,c(POS_FP_2013_01$TE))
set.rhs(test,c(50000,1,2,3,1))
lp.control(test,sense='max')
write.lp(test,'model.lp',type='lp')
solve(test)
get.objective(test)
```

I would like to add something like: for (i in 2013:2014) { for (j in 1:10)...}

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

renaming in R can be done just by setting it to something else with = or <- and then removing the original for example:

```
newFP = FP_2013_01
remove(FP_2013_01)
```

I use remove() regularly to clean up my workspace from big data.frames and data.tables.

Comment: Thanks tris -- this seems like a good way to remove data frames, but what I am more interested in is cycling through data frames. So taking one data frame, running it through the linear program, getting/saving the solution, and then running through a new (similarly named) data frame. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I would try putting them all in a list and iterating it with lapply or sapply possibly in more than one pass.  Otherwise the for loops can work if you pattern match on the names with a regex to pick the right data frames to process.  Suggest trying data.tables since they are more versatile and faster than data.frames - they have some builtin loop capabilities for processing logical groups for example.